# Size variation attachment size and blob size in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a general question about  blob size. Why we can see such significant difference between the size of the attached file and the size of the BLOB? For example, when I attach a 17MB tiff file, the BLOB size is 22MB. This difference is variable for different file types, but the larger the file, the bigger the difference. Can someone update on this.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by attaching a file, and how you measure the sizes. In short, make it reproducible.

Comment: And do not use PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: I have  csv file which is having 17 mb size and it contains only one record with blob data. After uploading into table, verified size of the record shows 22mb.  Used octet_lenght function to calculate blob size.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show a) the table definition b) how the file looks like (including the first couple of bytes of the large entry) c) the SQL statement you use to load the data d) what you get when you `SELECT substr(blobcol, 1, 20) FROM tab;`.